# Vincent visualizations are not displaying from the command line

Tags: python, python-2.7, data-visualization

I'm new to Python visualizations, and have been trying out [vincent's Quick Start examples](https://github.com/wrobstory/vincent) in iPython Notebook.

I pasted the following code in iPython Notebook and the visualization displayed.  Then I pasted the same code into (1) the shell and then (2) in a .py file that I ran from the command line, and both times no visualization showed up.  What am I doing wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import random
import vincent

#Iterable
list_data = [10, 20, 30, 20, 15, 30, 45]
vincent.core.initialize_notebook()
#Dicts of iterables
cat_1 = ['y1', 'y2', 'y3', 'y4']
index_1 = range(0, 21, 1)
multi_iter1 = {'index': index_1}
for cat in cat_1:
    multi_iter1[cat] = [random.randint(10, 100) for x in index_1]

cat_2 = ['y' + str(x) for x in range(0, 10, 1)]
index_2 = range(1, 21, 1)
multi_iter2 = {'index': index_2}
for cat in cat_2:
    multi_iter2[cat] = [random.randint(10, 100) for x in index_2]


line = vincent.Line(multi_iter1, iter_idx='index')
line.axis_titles(x='Index', y='Value')
line.legend(title='Categories')
```

Comment: I'll note that I've tried running from the command line with and without the vincent.core.initialize_notebook() line.  Both times the file completes successfully but nothing is displayed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to tell Vincent to output html and then use a browser to display the results. In a standalone script it doesn't make sense to do the `vincent.core.initialize_notebook()` line so you should remove it.

In your case just add the following line at then end of your script:

```
line.to_json('line.json', html_out=True, html_path='line.html')
```

Afterwards you can just double click the generated `line.html` file and it will open in your browser.  Take a look [here](https://vincent.readthedocs.org/en/latest/quickstart.html#output) for more details.